# Alarm is triggered before it is the time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm working on alarm clock app and everything works fine except one thing. My app triggers alarms if I make repeating alarm/s that are set for monday(and when the time is right for alarming it just does nothing). May be it's because I'm using debugging but rather not. What can I do about it?

My code:

```
int j = 0;
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MyService_alarm.this,MyReceiver_Alarm.class);
                if(string.length()>0) {
                    for (int i = string.length(); i > 0; i--) {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        if (string.contains("1")) {
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
                            string = string.replace("1","");
                            Log.e("Point_1","Monday");
                        } else if (string.contains("2")) {
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek() + 1);
                            string = string.replace("2","");
                            Log.e("Point_1","Tuesday");
                        } else if (string.contains("3")) {
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
                            string = string.replace("3","");
                            Log.e("Point_1","Wednesday");
                        } else if (string.contains("4")) {
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY);
                            string = string.replace("4","");
                            Log.e("Point_1","Thursday");
                        } else if (string.contains("5")) {
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
                            string = string.replace("5","");
                            Log.e("Point_1","Friday");
                        } else if (string.contains("6")) {
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
                            string = string.replace("6","");
                            Log.e("Point_1","Saturday");
                        } else if (string.contains("7")) {
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
                            string = string.replace("7","");
                            Log.e("Point_1","Sunday");
                        }
                        int y = intent.getIntExtra("Volume", 1);
                        intent1.putExtra("Size_ABC", y);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService_alarm.this, intent.getIntExtra("Size", 1) + j, intent1, 0);
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
                        Log.e("Point_1", "Size is " + y);
                        Log.e("Point_1", "Time is " + calendar.getTime());
                        j++;
                    }
                }else if(string.length() == 0){
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    int y = intent.getIntExtra("Volume", 1);
                    intent1.putExtra("Size_ABC", y);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService_alarm.this, intent.getIntExtra("Size", 1), intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                    //Log.e("Point_1", "Size2 is " + y);
                    //Log.e("Point_1","Extra " + intent1.getIntExtra("Size_ABC",1));
                    Log.e("Point_1","Time is " + calendar.getTime());
                }
```

My log shows that the time that alarm was set for.

```
Time is Mon Nov 21 20:01:00 GMT+05:00 2016
11-27 20:00:27.477  13285-13285/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
11-27 

20:00:27.497 // Time when alarm was triggered.

13285-13285/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Alarm!!!
```

May be someone has faced with this issue and already knows the answer the please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: share the codes ?

Comment: @angel-koh I've added my code. Take a look, please.